# Highcharts X-Axis as Time of Day

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, highcharts

I'm having trouble converting a time stamp from my PostgreSQL database. The time stamp is a date time with timezone so it looks like this

```
2016-04-24 20:52:04.291271-04
```

I would like the charts x-axis to display something like `April 24 8:52pm` etc

Currently I retrieve the query data from a `$.post` and the data looks like this

```
[2016-04-24 23:42:04.322966-04, 76.7]
[2016-04-25 00:02:04.327885-04, 77.28]
[2016-04-25 00:12:04.328069-04, 76.37]
[2016-04-25 00:22:04.329217-04, 76.15]
```

Currently it looks like [image: this]

My highchart creation

```
('div#GraphContainer').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        title : {
            text : name
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'        

        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'UoM'
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },
        series : [{
            type : 'area',
            name : 'IO Data',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
```

My code which reads the JSON from the PHP script.

```
var ioName = "Empty";
var newData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < retrievedData.length; i++) {


    var line = retrievedData[i];

    if(i == 0){
        ioName = line.name;                 
    }else {                             
        var newDataArray = [];
        console.log(line.date + ", " + line.value);                 
        newDataArray[0] = new Date(line.date.split(".")[0]);                    
        newDataArray[1] = Number(line.value);
        newData[i - 1] = newDataArray;
    }

}
```

Edit

[image: After Edit]

Comment: Try `newDataArray[0] = new Date(line.date.split(".")[0]).getTime();`.

Comment: @HalvorStrand Thanks! works great!